# Bind JSON data to date range picker calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using JSON to store data and using date range picker as the follows code.

```
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());

                if (!date1 || date2) {
                    $("#input1").val(dateText);
                    $("#input2").val("");
                    $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
                } else {
                    $("#input2").val(dateText);
                    $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
                }

                //$("#dateoutput").html("Chosen date is <b>" + date1 + "</b> - <b>" + dateText + "</b>");
            }
        });
    });
```

How can i bind data according to selected date range.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what it was you wanted to do, but I've made a JSFiddle from what I understood.

To test, do this:

1) I have saved an initial date as a JSON string, so you can click on "Load JSON Date" and it will parse the JSON string and store the values in the 2 input fields.

2) You can then select another date range, and click "Store JSON Data" and it will stringify the data.

3) Change the date

4) click "Load JSON Data" and it will reset the fields back to the data you stored.

http://jsfiddle.net/1xqbgshm/4/

The code does the following:

```
$("#store").click(function () {
    var date1 = $("#input1").val();
    var date2 = $("#input2").val();
    var dateObject = {
        "fromDate": date1,
        "toDate": date2
    };

    jsonString = JSON.stringify(dateObject);
    alert(jsonString);
});

$("#load").click(function () {
    var javascriptObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
    $("#input1").val(javascriptObject.fromDate);
    $("#input2").val(javascriptObject.toDate);
});
```

Does this help?